# Store an element of a list to another and update the value via the new list

Tags: python

```
s = [[5,4,7],[3,1,5],[1,7,4]]

corners  = [[ s[0][0], s[2][2] ]  ,  [ s[2][0], s[0][2] ]]

corners[0] = 2
print(s[0][0])
```

I need to assign `2` for `s[0][0]` while it's inside the corners List , My code didn't work

```
Output
5
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better, not sure what you are attempting here.

Comment: So you are trying to assign to variable `s`, by using `corners` variable?

Comment: @Capie When assign 2 for corners[0] it didn't changing s[] List

Comment: @Tushar yes , is there any different equaling method for it ?

Comment: of course not. `corners` is holding the value os `s` in certain positions. What you are doing is replacing that value by a integer but not overriding the value of s

Comment: @Capie do you know a method for do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects of type `int` are immutable. When you do this:

```
s = [1]
corners  = [s[0]]  # Technically, <1> here is the same object pointed to by s[0] AT THIS POINT IN TIME.

print(id(s[0]))  # Displays 9788608
print(id(corners[0]))  # Displays 9788608 - same
```

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html):

> #### immutable
>
> An object with a **fixed value**. Immutable objects include **numbers**, strings and tuples. **Such an object cannot be altered. A new object has to be created if a different value has to be stored.**

Thus doing the following would result to creating a new `int` in a different memory location other than the one pointed to by `s[0]`:

```
corners[0] = 2

print(id(s[0]))  # Displays 9788608 - same
print(id(corners[0]))  # Displays 9788640 - different
```

Thus now, `s[0]` points to the original int object of value `1` while `corners[0]` points to the newly created int object of value `2`.

If you want to update `s` via `corners`, you have to access a mutable value of `s` within `corners`. One way is through `list` as in the answer from @user1740577

Another way is by defining a custom class instance (which are mutable) instead of int (which is immutable).

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def set(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__value)

s = [
    [MyInt(5),MyInt(4),MyInt(7)],
    [MyInt(3),MyInt(1),MyInt(5)],
    [MyInt(1),MyInt(7),MyInt(4)],
]

corners  = [
    [s[0][0], s[2][2]],
    [s[2][0], s[0][2]]
]

corners[0][0].set(2)  # corners[0][0] points to the same object as s[0][0] and updates that same object
print(s[0][0])
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code : `corners  = [[ s[0][0], s[2][2] ]  ,  [ s[2][0], s[0][2] ]]` you pass value to corners. you need pass `list` with `address` then you can change `list` s.

Try this:

```
s = [[5,4,7],[3,1,5],[1,7,4]]

corners  = [[ s[0], s[2] ]  ,  [ s[2], s[0] ]]

corners[0][0][0] = 2
print(s[0][0])
# 2
```

Comment: @DilshanSiriwardhane is this your answer?

Comment: This works but , I really want an answer without changing corners variable

Comment: @DilshanSiriwardhane whit this : `corners  = [[ s[0][0], s[2][2] ]  ,  [ s[2][0], s[0][2] ]]`?

Comment: yes , If you can

Comment: I felt it impossible too , that's why I asked this for a solution , may be this hasn't an answer

Comment: yes , My program use this corners variable a lot  , I wanna do this without changing it  , Thank you trying helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [[5,4,7],[3,1,5],[1,7,4]]

corners  = [[0,0],[2,2],[2,0],[0,2]]
for i in corners:
    s[i[0]][i[1]] = 2
```

Try this. Corners holds the position where the corners in `s` are located.

Comment: I want to an answer without changing corners variable

Comment: Specify it on the question then please.

Comment: You changed the corners variable in your answer ,  I need an answer while corners  = [[ s[0][0], s[2][2] ]  ,  [ s[2][0], s[0][2] ]]